# How to ensure data is the same way when its fetched from other excel files and merged using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, merge

I have three Excel files that have data like this:
[image: 3_AM Data]
[image: 9_AM Data]
[image: 3_PM Data]
I have written a small code to read data from the three files and combine them into a single sheet like this:
[image: Combine_data_header]

So the number of rows should still be the same.

But I am getting repeating data which is also grouping the other data frames for some reason:

[image: current_output]

How do I fix this?

This is the code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Function to combine three Excel files
def combine_excel_files(file1, file2, file3, output_file):
    # Read the three Excel files
    df1 = pd.read_excel(file1)
    df2 = pd.read_excel(file2)
    df3 = pd.read_excel(file3)
    
    # Merge data frames based on a common column (adjust the column name as per your data)
    merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Device', 'IP'], how='right')
    merged_df = pd.merge(merged_df, df3, on=['Device', 'IP'], how='right')
    # Write the combined data frame to a new Excel file
    merged_df.to_excel(output_file, index=False)
```

Comment: Take a look at the unmerged `DataFrame`s. They don't look anything like something that could easily be merged into what you want. Pandas is used for processing data, not formatting Excel spreadsheets. I think you'll need to use a general Excel package like `openpyxl` to accomplish this. However, I strongly urge you to normalize these data if you really do need to process them, it will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: After a couple of runs using `concat`, I see what you meant. It was just slotting `dataframes` together (after dropping columns) without matching the key column